# QpushButton QTableWidget but when i add Menu action to button menu don't display why?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qmenu, graphical-programming

This is the code i want to run .

i put QpushButton in QTableWidget by setCellWidget but when i add Menu action to the button  the menu doesn't display why?

1. ```
     p = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test")
   ```
2. ```
      menuf= QtWidgets.QMenu(p)
   ```
3. ```
      p.setMenu(menuf)
   ```
4. ```
      Op= QtWidgets.QAction(menuf)
   ```
5. ```
      Pp= QtWidgets.QAction(menuf)
   ```
6. ```
      _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
   ```
7. ```
      Op.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Section"))
   ```
8. ```
      Pp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Charge"))
   ```
9. ```
      p.addAction(Op)
   ```
10. ```
       p.addAction(Pp)
    ```
11. ```
       self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(2,1,p)
    ```
12. ```
       thingWidget = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(2,1)
    ```

Comment: Please remove those line numbers, they are useless and distracting. Just use standard ways of [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Add the actions to the menu, not the button.